# Perl: how to write the ouput of a script in a new text file

Tags: perl

First of all, I'm a noob on perl, and I've tried to find the answer to that question on the internet but couldn't get (or understand) it...
So, I have a script that scan throught a text file and writes all line except those starting with an A.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open (my $file, "<", "/file.txt") or die "cannot open < file.txt $!";
while (<$file>) {
    unless (/^A/) {
        print;
    }
}
```

That works. But I get the results of this script in the terminal. Now, I just want these results to be saved in a new text file.
Can somebody help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `perl yourscript.pl > output.txt`

Comment: If you are using linux, you can also just do `grep -v "^A" file.txt > output.txt`. Or `perl -ne'print unless (/^A/)' > output.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Just open another file and print data to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $infile  = 'input.txt';
my $outfile = 'output.txt';

open my $infh,  "<", $infile  or die "Can't open $infile: $!";
open my $outfh, ">", $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";

while (<$infh>) {
    print $outfh $_ unless /^A/;
}

close($infh);
close($outfh);
```

But, generally speaking, you may use some perl magic combined with shell redirection instead. The whole script will become simple oneliner:

```shell
$ perl -ne 'print $_ unless /^A/;' input.txt > output.txt
```